# Validating Field with FieldReflector

Tags: botframework, formflow

I have a property that due to a previous question I disable it.

```
.Field(new FieldReflector<UploadDocumentForm>(nameof(UploadDocumentForm.StatusContent))
    .SetActive((state) => false))
```

But nevertheless it is possible that through another option I need to do a validation on that field, and send a message to the user depending on what he selects. Would it be possible to do it?
I do not know if a field can be valid having used the "FieldReflector".

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding verification step in formFlow - Check if topping is in stock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011844/adding-verification-step-in-formflow-check-if-topping-is-in-stock)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can leverage [`SetValidate()`](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d2/d1b/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_form_flow_1_1_advanced_1_1_field.html#a07b67338ce9069fa0ce60824f2c5aa2a) of `FieldReflector` Class to implement your requirement.

If you need to prompt user when he failed the valiadation, you can leverage the [Feedback](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d4/d7b/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_form_flow_1_1_validate_result.html#a42cb20123fe40abf33c040ec3a0ddd74) property of `ValidateResult`. If you want to always send message to your ueser, you can leverage `Message()` of `FormBuilder`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
...
private static string msg = "default";
...
...
.Field(new FieldReflector<Classification>(nameof(Choice))
                        .SetValidate(async (state, value) => {
                            var selection = (<ClassName>)value;
                            bool isValid = (int)selection > 2;
                            msg = $"Select Value is {selection}";
                            ValidateResult result = new ValidateResult
                            {
                                IsValid = isValid,
                                Value = selection,
                            };
                            if (!isValid)
                            {
                                result.Feedback = msg;
                            }
                            return result;
                        })
                       )
                   .Message(msg)
```